# Share via Facebook - Missing in list of choice - Android

Tags: android, facebook

I have written following code in my application to show user the "Sharing" option.

I can see "Email","Gmail" and "Youtube" but i can not see "Facebook" :(

```
try {

                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  mEvent.getName());  
                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");  
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtDesc.getText());
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send your email in:")); 

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Email faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

How to add "facebook" option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct MIME type for plain text is `text/plain`, not `plain/text`. Try that.